# How to assign FlowDocument of one RichTextBox to another in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

While assigning FlowDocument of one RichTextBox to another's I am getting a Exception that FlowDocument belongs to another TextBox . How to assign it .

```
  public ZoomedDialog(FlowDocument pFlowDocument)
            {

                txtRichContent.Document = pFlowDocument;
// this line throws exception "pFlowDocument belongs to another RichTextBox"
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question on the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2bc414fb-bcb9-4ecc-bb27-b55870085f1f/

And have a look at this question on SO: [Sharing FlowDocuments between multiple RichTextBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729629/sharing-flowdocuments-between-multiple-richtextboxes)

Based on the code you're showing I cannot decide what is appropriate to your setup.

Answer (score 2):

guys,

Try this solution :)!

```
 public static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rtb = (RichTextBox)obj;
        if (args.NewValue != null)
        {

            var doc = (FlowDocument) args.NewValue;
            if (doc.Tag is RichTextBox)
            {
                // clear belongs to another rtb.
                ((RichTextBox) doc.Tag).Document = new FlowDocument();
            }
            else
            {
                doc.Tag = rtb;
            }
            rtb.Document =doc;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution only works once, since you didn't update doc.Tag to be the new rtb, it will crashes the 2nd time you execute OnDocumentChanged. Bring doc.Tag = rtb; out of the else clause and it will work like a charm :)